# Building proto3 library in windows for C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto3

I've successfully generated .cc and .h files from a proto2 protobuf.  I've also followed the directions at https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/v2.6.1/vsprojects to create the lib to link against.  I created a couple projects in visual studio and was able to create two executables for the addressbook example.  Everything works as advertised.

I'm now looking at proto3, as it's likely I'll need support for objective-c.  It's trivial to download the precompiled binaries to generate .cc and .h files, but I cannot figure out how to duplicate the above steps in windows to create a lib for me to link against.  Has anyone else been able to do so?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to ask in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/protobuf ?

Comment: Doesn't protobuf provide a VS .sln file? That's how I compiled mine https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/protoc-alpha-3.1/vsprojects

Comment: I was trying the latest beta release, Beta 3 (5/2016).  This was released after alpha 3.1 (6/2015), but the vsprojects directory was removed on SHA:ee6b3d, PR https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/469.  Makes things difficult in windows.  I think I might just stick with proto2 until things settle with proto3.